# Spring security - endpoint only for admin

Tags: spring-boot, api, security

I would like to make "users" with the role "Administrator" accessible to endpoint "/admin/**", unfortunately no one has access to this API at this time. What am I doing wrong

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/login/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/books/*").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasAuthority("Administrator")
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JwtFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .csrf().disable();

    }
}
```

Comment: did you try using hasRole instead?

Comment: yes, i use UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken, so i added "ROLE_" to role name

Comment: Have you tried with the given answer?

Answer (score 0):

While using hasAuthority() method you need to add prefix `ROLE_` as used below. Also, make sure you are storing roles with prefix `ROLE_` in the database.

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/login/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_Administrator")
            .antMatchers("/api/books/*").authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JwtFilter(authenticationManager()));

    }
}
```